# Nest xmlDoc into existing xmlTextWriter

Tags: c, nested, libxml2, xmltextwriter

I think I'm missing something trivial but I'm losing a bunch of time on this, so its solution may be useful to others too:

I'm working with libxml2 2.9.8 (pure C, not C++ bindings) under linux.
I have an external (non-libxml) tree structure representing an XML file and I'm trying to write into a string representation using libxml2. All is trivial and working nice traversing it and writing using `xmlTextWriter` API (it is a struct with simple attributes, like

```
 typedef struct _simplifiedNode {
    char *tag,
    char *content,
    struct _simplifiedNode *parent,
    struct _simplifiedNodeList *children,
 } simplifiedNode;
```

), except at a certain point I encounter a string node that may contain the string representation of an xml document. I can parse it using the `xmlReadMemory` API, but then I need to nest it (and not its escaped string representation) into the on-going writer, including namespaces and attributes.

Is there a trivial way I am missing to do this recursively having the parsed doc/root element, without introspecting every sub-element?

e.g.

I'm producing the following document using `xmlTextWriter` API

```
<Title>
    TitleValue
</Title>
<Date>
    2018-11-26
</Date>
<Content>
```

The Content node in the non-libxml tree is a leaf node with tag `Content` containing a string like

```
char *content = "<SomeXmlComplexDocument ss:someattr=\"attrval\">Somecontent</SomeXmlComplexDocument>"
```

What I Want to achieve is, instead of having something like

```
<Content>&lt;SomeXmlComplexDocument&gt; ... </Content>
```

after having parsed and validated the content with `xmlReadMemory` to re-inject the document obtaining

```
<Content>
    <SomeXmlComplexDocument ss:someattr="attrval">Somecontent</SomeXmlComplexDocument>
</Content>
```

namespaces and attributes should be preserved.

Comment: Please give some sample xml - including the node which contains the string representation of an xml document.

Comment: Thank you, hope it is more clear now!

Comment: You can output the inner XML unescaped with [xmlTextWriterWriteRaw](http://xmlsoft.org/html/libxml-xmlwriter.html#xmlTextWriterWriteRaw), but if you want validation, you'll have to parse it somehow.

Comment: @nwellnhof since I feel like yours is the only way to go with libxml2 API (and that's how I implemented it right now), I'd like to accept yours as an answer, if you'd like to write it as one!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To serialize the inner XML fragments unescaped, you can simply use [`xmlTextWriterWriteRaw`](http://xmlsoft.org/html/libxml-xmlwriter.html#xmlTextWriterWriteRaw). This won't check whether the XML is well-formed, though. If you need validation, you'll have to parse the XML fragments at some point. Depending on the content model, you might have to use `xmlParseBalancedChunkMemory` instead of `xmlReadMemory`. It should also be possible to parse the result document in one go after it was written, but you'll lose information like original line numbers.